# Getting name and id value from select Laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I need a little help. I want to save also $item->name from the option to the Category database in the name column. Thanks for the help.

My blade code:

```
  <label>Select a Category</label>
   <select class="select2 form-control" for="cateId"  wire:model.lazy="cateId">
    <option value="">Select a Category</option>
      @foreach ($categorylist as $item)
       <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
```

my livewire controller:

```
    public $name;

    public function submit()
    {
       Category::create([
        'name' => $this->$item->name,
       ]);
     }
```

my Category model:

```
   protected $table = "category";
   protected $fillable = [
    'name',
   ];
```

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense to me, perhaps you can describe your question better? You have an ID from the `$categoryList` that is bound to the `cateId` property. That means that you can from that property find the category name in your function. It also makes little sense to use `$this->$item->name`, because they are  in different places.

Answer (score 0):

Just change option value like this:

```
   <label>Select a Category</label>
   <select class="select2 form-control" for="cateId"  wire:model.lazy="catName">
    <option value="">Select a Category</option>
      @foreach ($categorylist as $item)
       <option value="{{ $item->name }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
```

and get it from `$request->input('catName')`

Comment: Thank you but this not saving the id. I need both. I need name and id saved to the database.

Comment: Do you want to save Category name directly from a series of select input, which is created by `$categorylist` - This list is got by a database query, right ? I can not see the way or why you need that